# Display changed definitions of a header file in C

Tags: c

Lets say there is this code:

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

#define NAME "John Doe"

#endif
```

The definition NAME is used in one of the .c files

```
void print_name()
{
      printf("Name is: %s\n\n",NAME)
}
```

Is it possible to compile the program.. then change the value of NAME to "Johnny" and when the program is run again.. without compiling it, It prints "Johnny" instead of "John Doe"??

I am just curious to know if it is possible.
Thanks for any help or advice..

Comment: Not really, no.  If you want to be able to change something without recompiling, it'll need to be something that can be read into the program, such as a command-line argument or a configuration file.

Comment: Why are you hard-coding it in the program if you need to be able to change it?

Comment: The other option is to use a *persistent* data file external to your code holding a count and list of the names you want to cycle through and update the count each time to code is run.

Comment: You cannot do this in a portable manner. Still, there might be solution for certain  implementations. You'd most likely will run into trouble in any case if the "new" string is larger then the "old" string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not trivially. Included files get pasted into the source and the source nor the headers no longer technically exist in the binary output.

You can however edit the binary, and if you do it right (e.g., can't replace a 10-character string with a 3-character replacement as that'd misalign stuff), you can get it to work.

Example: (your example simplified):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
      printf("Name is: %s\n\n","John Doe");
}
```

Compile, run, edit, re-run:

```
$ gcc file.c 
$ ./a.out
  Name is: John Doe

$ sed -i 's/John Doe/Johnny\x00\x00/' a.out
$ ./a.out
  Name is: Johnny
```

Comment: he can add padding of null bytes though

Comment: @Malina Exactly ;)

Comment: Very poor solution as executables are often CRC (or there method) protected to make viruses development harder

Comment: There aren't going to be any "good" solutions when doing something the isn't designed to be done....

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it was a "good" solution. Just that you can "get it to work" if you're in the mood for some hacking (and the executable isn't hash-protected). :)

Comment: That's far too dangerous, as you don't know if there's place in the string to  allow for it to be changed, you can break the executable completely if there isn't. And that has nothing to do with macro definitions in C.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean by not re-compiling. You need to change the program file somehow, but you can do that in various ways:

- A hex editor other "direct" modification of the executable file, where you can look for the string "John Doe" and replace it with "Johny" (with extra null-byte padding), as described by [PSkocik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50419620/27302) and [MustacheMoses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50419532/27302)
- Depending on the modification, I am fairly sure there are more specialized tools for attempting them. I don't know what they are, though.
- You could also make `NAME` be an `extern` variable instead of a macro, with `extern char *NAME;` in a header file and `char *NAME = "John Doe";` in a separate .c file. Then if you want to change the name, you just need to change it in the one, small, file where it's defined, re-compile that, and then just re-link with the rest of the program. That still involves some re-compiling, but it's a lot faster than re-compiling everything.

To make a recommendation I'd need to know your use case, but the third option I mention is a lot more common than just modifying an executable file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use something called a hex editor to change the contents of stored strings in the generated executable.

Comment: @JaimeT not-too-"smart" nnon-hex editor. Perhaps a Stream EDitor (sed) like in my asnwer :).

Answer (score 0):

A macro is something that cannot change without recompiling again.  It's not a variable or something you can operate on, so it's imposible to make a macro to give a different value than programmed, but to change the value and recompile.

You can give the macro different definitions, based on the value of another macro (one that you can pass the compiler on the command line when compiling) but anyway, you need to recompile the source again.  This allows you to tweak the file without having to edit it, but never avoids you to recompile it again.

## source.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef VERSION
#define VERSION 0
#endif /* VERSION */

#if VERSION
#define NAME "John Doe"
#else
#define NAME "Johnny Guitar"
#endif

int main()
{
    puts("the winner is " NAME);
} /* main */
```

that you can compile with

```
$ cc source.c
$ a.out
the winner is Johnny Guitar
$ _
```

or

```
$ cc -DVERSION=1 source.c
$ a.out
the winner is John Doe
$ -
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if the program opens the header file, scans to find `#define NAME` line, then gets the value. Something like very simple preprocessor. And if you add #if or #ifdef conditions, the final value may be invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Not. Definitions are part of the preprocessor and aren't not the C variables and symbols. During the preprocessing definitions are textually replaced by their values
If you need to change something during the program execution you need the C variable

```
  char NAME[] = "John Doe";
```

And you are done

Comment: where do i need char NAME[] = "John Doe";

Comment: I will not answer it as it is too basic question. Please start from the C book and learn the basics